# Issues upgrading ios13.1 to 13.2 - NavigationLink - tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigationlink, ios13.2, ios13.1.2

I built an app using both UIKit and swiftUI.

It worked fine with ios13.1 but with ios 13.2 I have bugs:

I'm showing a **SwiftUI View** in a **UIViewController** (using **HostingController**). This view is composed with elements wrapped in **NavigationLink**. 
When clicking on this element, the next view doesn't show, although the navbar is ok, and when clicking back, the app crashes with:

```
<Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'>
```

Is it a bug related to ios 13.2 ? Any clue how to fix it ?

Here is my code:

UIController :

< class MyController: UIViewController {

```
var delegate: MenuItemsDelegate?

let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: MyView_UI())

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        view.backgroundColor = BACKGROUND_COLOR_D
    } else {
        view.backgroundColor = PALE_GREY
    }

    setupViews()
    setNavigationBar()
}

 func setupViews() {
    addChild(vc)
    view.addSubview(vc.view)
    vc.didMove(toParent: self)
    setupConstraints()
 }


 func setupConstraints() {
    vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

     [
        vc.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
          vc.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
          vc.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
        vc.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),

         ].forEach {$0.isActive = true }

 }


func setNavigationBar() {
    title = ""
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "slidingNotif").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal),  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleMenuToggle))
    setNavigationRightBarButtons()
}

@objc func handleMenuToggle() {
    delegate?.handleMenuToggle(forMenuOption: nil)
}
```

} >

MyView_UI:
<
    var body: some View {

```
    ScrollView{
        VStack(spacing: 15) {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView_UI(some param )){
                    ThirdView_UI(some param), height: 150)
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView_UI(some param)){
                    ThirdView_UI(some, height: 150)
                }
            }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
       //autres HStack(...)

   }
 }
```

}

>

MyView_UI and SecondView_UI are showing fine, but app crashes when going back

Comment: Hi Emilie, you should format better your question and add some code. Probably I could help you to solve your issue

Comment: @AndreaMiotto Thanks, I completed with some code, hoping my question is a bit clearer. It all works fine with 13.1 but crashes with 13.0 and 13.2

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a bug in the bridge between UIKit and SwiftUI. It is somehow related to [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/124757), but here the cause is that the UIHostingController is embedded, as a child, within another UIViewController. Unfortunately, this also occur if you use some standard container view controller, like UIPageViewController.

Here are some logs, right before the crash:

```
// we have ViewController0 in the navigation stack
// here we push ViewController1, that embeds UIHostingController, in our case - EmbeddedHostingController
pushViewController(_:animated:)
viewController: ViewController1
viewControllers: [ViewController0]
viewControllers: [ViewController0, ViewController1]

// here we tap a NavigationLink
// we can see that the pushed view controller is DestinationHostingController, coming from the framework
pushViewController(_:animated:)
viewController: DestinationHostingController<AnyView>
viewControllers: [ViewController0, ViewController1]
viewControllers: [ViewController0, ViewController1, DestinationHostingController<AnyView>]

// here we tap back in the navigation bar
// the DestinationHostingController is being popped, as expected
popViewController(animated:)
viewControllers:[ViewController0, ViewController1, DestinationHostingController<AnyView>]
super.result: DestinationHostingController<AnyView>
viewControllers: [ViewController0, ViewController1]

// this is the wrong part - the framework is triying to pop our embedded hosting controller, but because it is not part of the navigation stack - we get a crash
popToViewController(_:animated:)
viewController: EmbeddedHostingController
viewControllers: [ViewController0, ViewController1]
```

A valid workaround for this would be to use custom UINavigationController subclass, override `popToViewController` and return `nil` when the viewController is of UIHostingController type.

There is another weird crash, that can sometimes occur - the navigation controller is trying to pop itself.

Here is an example solution:

```
private protocol HostingController {}
extension UIHostingController: HostingController {}

class RootNavigationController: UINavigationController {
  override func popToViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]? {
    if #unavailable(iOS 13.3) {
      if #available(iOS 13.2, *) {
        if viewController is HostingController, viewController.parent !== self {
          return nil
        }

        if viewController === self {
          return nil
        }
      }
    }

    return super.popToViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
  }
}
```